# how to set up Laravel 9 project with Vuetify and Vite

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite

Question:

I'm currently working on a Laravel 9 project with Vite and I'm trying to integrate Vuetify into it. I've followed the instructions on the Vuetify documentation, but the styles are not being applied

**app.js**

```
import App from "./App.vue";

// Vuetify
import "vuetify/styles";
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
});

createApp(App).use(vuetify).mount("#app");
```

**vite.config.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import laravel from "laravel-vite-plugin";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(), laravel(["resources/css/app.css", "resources/js/app.js"])],
});
```

**plugins/vuetify.js**

```
import "@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css";
import "vuetify/styles";

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    ssr: true,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your JS and CSS files integrated in your view?

In the head tag put the following line:

```
 @vite('resources/path/to/app.css') 
 @vite('resources/path/to/app.js')
```

Now the vite will be implemented in your view and styles should apply!

Answer (score 0):

**I found a solution, edit app.js and add lines**

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";

//add this
import { aliases, mdi } from "vuetify/iconsets/mdi-svg";
//

// Vuetify
import "vuetify/styles";
import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,

//and this
    icons: {
        defaultSet: "mdi",
        aliases,
        sets: {
            mdi,
        },
    },
//

});

createApp(App).use(vuetify).mount("#app");
```